# Microsoft Team System and Java

Tags: java, tfs

We're starting a project written in Java in a company which works purely on MS technologies. Microsoft Team System is used as source control tool. A question is whether we should try to integrate Eclipse with MTS (which makes sense from the top level as there would be still a single repository for the company) or we should try to setup another source control tool - most likely Subversion (which makes sense from developers perspective)?

Anyone tried to marry Team System with Java projects? Does it makes any sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Team Foundation Server with Eclipse with Teamprise.

As for whether it makes sense or not depends on the environment. If you are one of many projects, just one that happens to be Java, it does not make sense to reinvent the wheel and implement SVN, unless the business is making a clean deliniation between Java projects and MS projects ... and realizing they have two places to get metrics for projects, which can be nasty.

I would vote on TFS, personally, as there is already an investment in TFS.

Comment: Worth noting that you have to pay for Teamprise, they have a free version but it only works against Codeplex opensource projects.

Comment: This is no longer the case since Teamprise was bought by Microsoft and they have re-released it as Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010

Answer (score 1):

I work on a project that uses eclipse and teamprise to use TFS with java.  While the experience isn't perfect, it does work fairly well.

Since your company already has an investment in TFS I would stick with that if you and your team have comfort with TFS as a version control system.  However, if you are comfortable with subversion and not with TFS, then I say just make the switch to subverison and you won't look back.

Answer (score 1):

My team is in a similar situation...our company has recently standardized on TFS for source control, and we are a Java group (with many other teams in my company being Microsoft...thus the decision to go with TFS).  We are migrating from VSS, so we're actually pretty happy to get to a more modern system (although I would have preferred SVN).

We use [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and with version 8.1 they now have integrated TFS support.  So far it seems to be working quite well.  We also use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) for our continuous integration server and there is a nice TFS plugin for that, too.  From our Ant scripts we are using the free [Teamprise Ant Tasks](http://www.teamprise.com/products/ant/) when we need to access TFS.

Answer (score 0):

One thing the might be helpful if you end up using tfs (but not teamprise) is the Team Foundation Power Tools 2008 adds Window Explorer extension support (although I wish it has ‘get specific version’ as a menu option)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx

From the above link...
"Windows Shell Extension  - Allows core version control operations within Windows Explorer without using Team Explorer."

Answer (score 0):

It's free now (after March 2012).

[Microsoft.com; Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25125#overview)