# TFS plugin for eclipse

Tags: tfs, eclipse-plugin

Are there any TFS plugins available for the Eclipse IDE? We are trying to centralise our SCM, and since we also develop Java 2 EE applications, we would like to have TFS integration in eclipse.

Which plugins are available?  Which have you found most useful.

I heard that Microsoft may be releasing one, does anyone know about this?

I have had a look and found the reviews of Teamprise looks good, however would like to have > 1 option!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sup>(February 2010)</sup>
There might not be a *free* plugin and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634962/microsoft-team-system-and-java) reports several alternative to a direct Eclipse integration.
Otherwise, there is [**Teamprise**](https://web.archive.org/web/20100110054438/http://www.teamprise.com:80/products/plugin/):

[image: teamprise plugin]

---

<sup>(Octobre 2010)</sup>
As [Martin (mrhinsh)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11799/mrhinsh-martin-hinshelwood) details in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264016/tfs-plugin-for-eclipse/3534422#3534422) (go upvote it):

- Since Teamprise was aquired by Microsoft it has become **Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010** (as mentioned by the [teamprise.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140409065107/http://www.teamprise.com/) page, and detailed in the [Microsoft teamprise FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20120906005124/http://www.microsoft.com:80/pathways/teamprise/FAQ.htm) page).
- It might be accessible for anyone with a MSDN licence.
  ([thijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26796/thijs) confirms in the comment: "**its free with an MSDN ([Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN](https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798&site_id=501446&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&redirect_uri=https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signedin&nonce=3b3bdf98-778c-44ee-8632-38dbe2b24209&state=realm=app.vssps.visualstudio.com&allow_passthrough=True&reply_to=https%253A%252F%252Fmy.visualstudio.com%253A443%252F%253Fwt.mc_id%253Do%25257emsft%25257emsdn%25257eoldPortal%2526amp%25253butm_source%253DMSDNPortal%2526auth_redirect%253Dtrue&nonce=3b3bdf98-778c-44ee-8632-38dbe2b24209&resource=https://management.core.windows.net/&cid=3b3bdf98-778c-44ee-8632-38dbe2b24209&wsucxt=1&githubsi=true&msaoauth2=true&prompt=select_account)) account**")

---

<sup>(March 2012, mentioned in the comments by [Buck Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957482/buck-hodges), Development manager for Microsoft Team Foundation Server):</sup>

The blog post "[Even Better Access to Team Foundation Server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/even-better-access-to-team-foundation-server/)" by [Brian Harry MS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/brian%20harry%20ms/) announces:

> **Starting today, we are eliminating the requirement to purchase Team Explorer Everywhere separately**.

> - Before today,

- Team Explorer Everywhere users had to purchase both a Client Access License (CAL) and the Team Explorer Everywhere software,
- whereas Visual Studio Team Explorer users only had to purchase a CAL – the Visual Studio Team Explorer software has always been a free download (TE 2008, TE 2010, TE 11 Beta) for users who had a license to access a TFS server.
  Starting today the story is the same for Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE 2010 with SP1, TEE 11 Beta).

Comment: Since Teamprise was aquired by Microsoft it has become Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010. I "think" it is now free if you have an MSDN licence.

Comment: Confirmed; its free with an MSDN (Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN) account

Comment: as of today available with these MSDN subscriptions : Developer AA; BizSpark Admin; BizSpark; VS Ultimate with MSDN (VL); VS Ultimate with MSDN (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN); VS Ultimate with MSDN (NFR FTE);

Comment: can we use this while developing android projects using eclipse

Comment: It is now free: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/08/even-better-access-to-team-foundation-server.aspx

Comment: @BuckHodges: Excellent! I have included your update in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 21):

**Option 1: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010**

With the launch of Visual Studio 2010 ALM Microsoft also released [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=af1f5168-c0f7-47c6-be7a-2a83a6c02e57&displaylang=en) which is an Eclypse plug in.

This is fully supported by Microsoft (they bought Teamprise) and supports:

Any of the following IDEs:

- Eclipse 3.0 to 3.5 on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, AIX, or HP-UX.
- IBM Rational Application Developer 6.0 to 7.5 on Windows.
- IBM Rational Application Developer 7.0 to 7.5 on Linux.
- Additional IDEs based on Eclipse 3.0 to 3.5 are supported including Adobe Flex Builder 3 and Aptana Studio 2.0.

**Option 2: SVN Bridge**

You can use the [SVN Bridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) to use any product that would normaly connect to SVN to connect to Team Foundation Server. Magic :)

Comment: Free if you have the right MSDN subscription

Answer (score 3):

Team Explorer Everywhere is now a free download.  Here is the official post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/08/even-better-access-to-team-foundation-server.aspx.  Prior to March 8, 2012, it was not free.

You must have a client access license (CAL) for TFS, and that comes with MSDN subscriptions, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Teamprise integration I found to be filled with bugs, after days of trying to get it to work with the Zend IDE 6.1, I stopped.  We decided as a large corporation to not use TFS for our OS development.

Comment: I think if you looked again you would see a vast improvement just from the tools having to now go through Microsofts QA process.

Comment: I was actually able (finally) to get this to work, I had to not use the Zend IDE, but build my IDE from the base eclipse package.  I tried using the Eclipse php pre-assembled IDE but ran into the same issues as with the Zend version.

Comment: What I did find was that if I used the base Eclipse IDE, added PHP support and then added the TFS support all individually, it would work.

Answer (score 2):

To provide updated information:

The eclipse plugin update site is public available and is free!

Installation instructions are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301122.aspx

If you want to install stable release http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs

If you want to install and test the preview release
    http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs/preview

Comment: I just installed this on FlashBuilder 4.6 (which is Eclipse) and after a few attemps the plugin failed horribly and it made my Eclipse slower (not responding)

Comment: I am just providing more information for an answer that is almost 3 years old

Answer (score 1):

have a look at SvnBridge, then you can use an SVN plugin in Eclipse e.g. Subclipse (or svn command line or tortoisesvn depending on your development environemt)

Other than that you're stuck with paying MS for the TEE plugin.