# Are there any TFS plugins available for the Force.com IDE?

Tags: salesforce

Are there any TFS plugins available for the Force.com IDE? We are trying to centralise our CRM, and  we would like to have TFS integration in Force.com IDE.

Which plugins are available? Which have you found most useful.

Does anyone know about this, which plugins are available?

We need this as we already have a historical repository in TFS with respect to the existing application framework. We are likely to add couple of more Force.com utilities to the framework. Hence it would be more mangeable to have a single repository rather having it on multiple ends. Any Idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, force.com IDE is essentially a customized Eclipse so a TFS plugin for eclipse should in theory work, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264016/tfs-plugin-for-eclipse).

Though, I am not certain why you need it, SF sandbox itself in combination with Force.com IDE is a form of merge-based Apex source repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify things first. The Force.com IDE is built as a plugin for the eclipse editor. There are many many other plugins for eclipse. What you want is http://www.teamprise.com/index.html - this however is not free. If you have an MSDN account it should be available to you already.

I use eclipse with the Force.com plugin and the subclipse (subversion) plugin side by side and it works quite well. So I'd assume with a bit of tinkering you can get teamprise working alongside the force.com plugin.