# Problems with installing TFS plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs

I wanted to install TFS plugin for Eclipse (Juno).
I pressed Help->Install New Software. Then, "Add" -> entered the address which written at Microsoft web-site (http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs/).

Eclipse tried to do load it for some time, then it gave me an error:
"Communication with repository at http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs/ failed.
Read timed out"

After that mistake I updated all the plugins and Eclipse, restarted Eclipse and operating system (Windows 7). The error was the same all the time.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found out that instead of the way described above, it can be downloaded directly from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661
Then, it can be installed as "From Archive"

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are using (or not! using) a proxy connection
adjust your "Preferences - General - Network Connection" settings

instructions -> [TFS plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264016/tfs-plugin-for-eclipse/16034241#16034241)