# Feasibility of using Eclipse IDE with TFS plugin and Aptana Studio plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, tfs, aptana, teamprise

I'm looking at various options (IDEs - Rails specific) that can be used for Ruby on Rails development with TFS for SCM. I'm currently working on a Rails 2.1 app which uses Ruby 1.8.7 and I consider it important to mention this explicitly because I need an IDE that could support the Ruby and Rails versions mentioned above (in the meanwhile I'll be checking this from my end as well).

With some amount of research I've found that one can have an Eclipse IDE along with the below two plugins for RoR development

1. TFS Plugin that's provided by [Teamprise](http://www.teamprise.com/index.html) as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264016/tfs-plugin-for-eclipse) .
2. [Aptana Studio plugin for Eclipse](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) .

I just wanted to confirm if a setup as mentioned above can coexist? What are the pros and cons of using both these plugins within the Eclipse IDE for day to day Rails development?